# Typed.js - Keep div scrolled to bottom as div increases in size unless user interacts with scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I am using Typed.js to dynamically add lines of text to a div. After a few seconds, the fixed-height div develops a scrollbar. I want to keep the scrollbar scrolled to the bottom as content is continually added without editing the code of my Typed.js library.

I was able to accomplish this with the code:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.getElementById('scrollBottom');
  elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
}, 500);
```

However, if a user tries to scroll up, the code will obviously force the div to scroll back to the bottom. Instead, I'd like it to allow the user to scroll freely if they please (but by default, without user interaction, scroll to bottom).

The catch: I can't execute the scroll every time a new line of code is added; essentially, I do not know when it will be added. That's why I initially thought of using a frequent interval (shown above).

Is there a way to end the above function if a user clicks on the div's scrollbar?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Easy. Something like this:

```
    var youInterval; 

    function startInterval(){

        youInterval = setInterval(function() {
           var elem = document.getElementById('scrollBottom');
           elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;
        }, 500);

    }

    //If user scrolls, stop interval
    document.addEventListener('scroll', function (event) {
      if (event.target.id === 'scrollBottom') { // or any other filtering condition        

            clearInterval(youInterval);
      }
    }, true /*Capture event*/);

    //And start it whenever you need
    startInterval();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much :)